# Animate my right sidebar with jQuery for hiding it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 3-columns page where I would like to hide my right sidebar with a nice animation (thanks to jQuery). Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I created a demo online here: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhfXX/

My template is somewhat special because my columns are defined like this:

- menu (on the left) is fixed
- content (center of the page) is full remaining width space
- sidebar (on the right) is fixed

Does someone have a solution for me?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/yhfXX/2/

Instead of changing the margin of the sidebar I'm just removing the width of it.

Comment: @Bronzato glad to hear it. :)  Took the idea from http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 1):

You can change the animate call to hide and specify the transition to use or just use the hide function by itself.

```
$('#sidebar').hide( 500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. it will look more better. reducing width increase height of sidebar(text content breaks in new line).

Just set your side bar position to relative and reduce it's right position to -150px (negetive value of width).

```
overflow-x:hidden should be set for parent container
```

See the demo -> 
[jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/rxVBU8)